# can someone explain me why the grammar of for, while, do-while statement define that the condition part within the header is an "Expression"

Tags: javascript, context-free-grammar, ecmascript-2020

Can someone explain to me why the grammar of **[for](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-for-statement), [while](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-while-statement), [do-while](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-do-while-statement)** statement's define that the condition part within the header is an **["Expression"](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-Expression)** and can someone explain me what the below thing means

```js
Expression[In, Yield, Await] :
      AssignmentExpression[?In, ?Yield, ?Await]
      Expression[?In, ?Yield, ?Await] , AssignmentExpression[?In, ?Yield, ?Await]
```

As you see there is no [Literal](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-Literal) at the right hand side after the **non-terminal** *`Expression[In, Yield, Await] :`* but still it's possible to write [literals](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-Literal) within the header of a *`for-statement, while-statement, do-while statement`*

```js
for (var i = 0; null; i ++) {
             /* ^^^^ */
             /* null */   
}

while (null) {
    /* ^^^^ */
    /* null */
}

do {} while (null) ; 
          /* ^^^^ */
          /* null */
```

And it's also possible to write [function expressions](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-FunctionExpression) within the header of those statement's even though [FunctionExpression](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-FunctionExpression) is not present in the right hand side of **non-terminal** *`Expression[In, Yield, Await] :`*

```js
for (var i = 0; function () {}; i ++) ;
             /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
             /*  functionExpr  */

while (function () {}) ;
    /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
    /*  functionExpr  */
    
do ; while (function () {}) ;
         /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
         /*  functionExpr  */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me some search in the documentation, but what i found is (summarized):

```
Expression: 
    AssignmentExpression
```

Then, among others:

```
AssignmentExpression: 
    LeftHandSideExpression
```

So we can go deeply in the nesting:

```
LeftHandSideExpression: 
    NewExpression

NewExpression: 
    MemberExpression

MemberExpression: 
    PrimaryExpression
```

And find out that PrimaryExpression contains many other items, but also *Literal* and *FunctionExpression*:

```
PrimaryExpression[Yield, Await]:
     this
     IdentifierReference[?Yield, ?Await]
     Literal
     ArrayLiteral[?Yield, ?Await]
     ObjectLiteral[?Yield, ?Await]
     FunctionExpression
     ClassExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
     GeneratorExpression
     AsyncFunctionExpression
     AsyncGeneratorExpression
     RegularExpressionLiteral
     TemplateLiteral[?Yield, ?Await, ~Tagged]
     CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList[?Yield, ?Await]
```

I hope my answer it's enough clear and clarifies your doubts